# Which dpdk version is suitable for --- Intel Corporation "82541PI" (NIC) Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05) and i am running dpdk on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sdn, nic, dpdk

I am trying to run dpdk(19 or latest version) on ubuntu host which is having two NIC(Intel).
But i can see only one port, i mean to say dpdk detecting only one NIC.
The NIC (Intel Corporation "82541PI" Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05)) which is not detected by dpdk.

So, please can any one help me that exactly which dpdk version support to this physical NIC(82541PI).
If any one can help me, it would be a great favour.

Answer (score 0):

Likely NIC 82541PI is not supported in mentioned DPDK version, supported Intel based NIC hardware can be found [here](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/nics/intel/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay but as i asked and as you said NIC 82541PI is not supporting for latest version of dpdk . But can you tell me for which version of dpdk this NIC supports.Thank you.

Comment: And also i gone through the link which you mentioned but i didn't found any information about my NIC.

Comment: Yes, it's not supported in any version of DPDK. You should consider procuring hardware which is supported for your experiments.

Comment: Thank you very much